# How do I compile a Visual Studio project from the command-line?

Tags: c++, python, visual-studio-2008, command-line

I'm scripting the checkout, build, distribution, test, and commit cycle for a large C++ solution that is using [Monotone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_%28software%29), [CMake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake), Visual Studio Express 2008, and custom tests.

All of the other parts seem pretty straight-forward, but I don't see how to compile the Visual Studio solution without getting the GUI.

The script is written in Python, but an answer that would allow me to just make a call to: os.system would do.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

I know of two ways to do it.

**Method 1**
The first method (which I prefer) is to use [msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx):

```
msbuild project.sln /Flags...
```

**Method 2**
You can also run:

```
vcexpress project.sln /build /Flags...
```

The vcexpress option returns immediately and does not print any output. I suppose that might be what you want for a script.

Note that DevEnv is not distributed with Visual Studio Express 2008 (I spent a lot of time trying to figure that out when I first had a similar issue).

So, the end result might be:

```
os.system("msbuild project.sln /p:Configuration=Debug")
```

You'll also want to make sure your environment variables are correct, as msbuild and vcexpress are not by default on the system path. Either start the Visual Studio build environment and run your script from there, or modify the paths in Python (with [os.putenv](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.putenv)).

Comment: This is also applicable to Visual Studio 2010 Express.

Comment: msbuild doesn't seem to be shipping with VS 2008

Comment: And can you run this outside of an "MSVS shell"?

Comment: How do you run MSBuild? I have Visual Studio 2022 with the C++ libraries installed, but when I open a PowerShell prompt and run `msbuild`, it says `The term 'msbuild' is not recognized as the name of a`...

Answer (score 62):

MSBuild usually works, but I've run into difficulties before.  You may have better luck with

```
devenv YourSolution.sln /Build
```

Comment: MSBuild doesn't work with Visual Fortran projects ( *.vfproc ).  Thanks for pointing me towards devenv, which does.

Comment: You can also specify the config:`devenv YourSolution.sln /Build Debug`

Comment: Works great. One can also do rebuild using the below command
`devenv YourSolution.sln /rebuild`

Comment: Also one can rebuild for release or debug mode by just appending debug or release after one space. For eg: `devenv YourSolution.sln /rebuild release` or `devenv YourSolution.sln /rebuild debug`

Comment: How do you target `.prj` project  within `.sln `soluton?

Comment: using cmake, the msbuild approach fails due to missing dependencies..likely vs env stuff i dont want to fight with. whereas this solution "just worked"(tm) thank you

Comment: If you are targeting C++ project, the following worked smoothly:
devenv solutionname.sln /rebuild DEBUG /Project projectname

Comment: You can also specify the config with platform: ```devenv YourSolution.sln /Build "Debug|x64"```

Comment: How do you get the command line to recognize devenv? I have Visual Studio 2022 with the C++ libraries installed, but when I open a PowerShell prompt and run `devenv`, it says `The term 'devenv' is not recognized as the name of a`...

Answer (score 31):

To be honest I have to add my 2 cents.

You can do it with **msbuild.exe**. There are many version of the  **msbuild.exe**.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\msbuild.exe
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\msbuild.exe
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\msbuild.exe
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe

Use version you need. Basically you have to use the last one.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe

So how to do it.

1. Run the **COMMAND** window
2. Input the path to msbuild.exe

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe

1. Input the path to the project solution like

> "C:\Users\Clark.Kent\Documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1.sln"

1. Add any flags you need after the solution path.
2. Press **ENTER**

Note you can get help about all possible flags like

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe /help

Comment: I really like how you have added the details for new developers like where to find msbuild etc.

Answer (score 18):

Using `msbuild` as pointed out by others worked for me but I needed to do a bit more than just that. First of all, `msbuild` needs to have access to the compiler. This can be done by running:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
```

Then `msbuild` was not in my $PATH so I had to run it via its explicit path:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" myproj.sln
```

Lastly, my project was making use of some variables like `$(VisualStudioDir)`. It seems those do not get set by `msbuild` so I had to set them manually via the `/property` option:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" /property:VisualStudioDir="C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2013" myproj.sln
```

That line then finally allowed me to compile my project.

**Bonus**: it seems that the command line tools do not require a registration after 30 days of using them like the "free" GUI-based Visual Studio Community edition does. With the Microsoft registration requirement in place, that version is hardly free. Free-as-in-facebook if anything...

Answer (score 6):

[MSBuild is your friend.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171452.aspx)

```
msbuild "C:\path to solution\project.sln"
```

Comment: I've seen that fail in odd situations due to differences in how MSBuild and DevEnv process .sln files.

Comment: This is the ideal solution.  But in our case we have a MSDEV (Visual Studio 2019) plug in that triggers a 2 pass build.  This is for internal reasons but msbuild will only build a target 1 time.  We have special files that require the EXE be built twice, once in a stub mode.  Then a process runs the exe to create files used in pass2.

Answer (score 3):

DEVENV works well in many cases, but on a WIXPROJ to build my WIX installer, all I got is "CATASTROPHIC" error in the Out log.

This works:
MSBUILD /Path/PROJECT.WIXPROJ /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release

Answer (score 3):

`dotnet build` seems to be the newest way to build your solution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build

Answer (score 2):

Both MSBuild and DevEnv are, rightfully, suggested in the answers here as the means to build from the command line. I wanted to point out that Microsoft says this about that: *"In general, DEVENV is preferred over using MSBuild directly, because you can let Visual Studio handle the complexities of MSBuild."*

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-160#command-line-project-management-tools)

Comment: Maybe the article changed, but I followed your link and it doesn't say anywhere that DEVENV is preferred. And actually the [main page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2019) for DEVENV recommends using MSBUILD.

Comment: Indeed! It would appear they took that statement out on that page. The Wayback Machine verifies this: https://web.archive.org/web/20210502101153/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-160

Answer (score 1):

For build  x64 platform targets with vs2019:

**clean the projects**

devenv *.sln  /Clean "Release|x64"

---

**build or rebuild the projects**

devenv  *.sln  /Build  "Release|x64"

devenv  *.sln  /Rebuild  "Release|x64"