# Quickest Way To See If A Solution Builds?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line, build

Currently, the way I check to see if my solution builds is to make a new checkout, open it in VS, and build it.  This is pretty slow, I imagine there's a way to do this via the command line or batch file, and build the files in the trunk, instead of checking out a new copy.

Any help here would be appreciated, will make my life easier, thanks!

Comment: Introduce continuous integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498106/how-do-i-compile-a-visual-studio-project-from-the-command-line) a look. The general gist is using [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx).

Comment: Hi, MSBuild takes an eternity to run on my solution.  I just point it to my .sln, and it's still running (has been a few minutes already!).  Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: If VS is slow, and MSBuild is slow, my thoughts are that this is either a HUGE solution, or you have very costly pre/post-build operations. If you just want to see that source code compiles, try creating a build configuration that only compiles source; no installer, no publishing, no XCOPY, just source.