# Makefile for c# project & compiling from command line

Tags: c#, .net

How can I create makefile for a c# project? Or, how can I compile my project from the command line?

The project name is Ex6-Assembler and the cs files are: main.cs, code.cs, SymbolTable.cs, parser.cs

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498106/how-do-i-compile-a-visual-studio-project-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 4):

For 'make'-alternative you can use MSBuild, you can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx)
Or if you want, you can just compile files, calling csc.exe as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1700bbwd%28v=vs.71%29.)

Comment: csc.exe? where should i write it? in what folder should i be (in commnand prompt) whem i try it it shows error message "command is not recognizable...

Comment: Go to your Visual Studio Bin folder, on my machine it's "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\" and run VCVARS32.bat file. It will pop up Command Prompt with appropriate folders added to PATH.

Answer (score 3):

look there for build your application via commandline:
https://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2007/08/31/compiling-c-code-from-de-code-line.aspx

here is the offical msdn page to this topic:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

you can find more details on the msdn:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1700bbwd%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

i am use **run_built.bat** file there are code

```
C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /target:Build build.msbuild
PAUSE
```

and build.msbuild:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="Build">
        <MSBuild Projects="MyProject.sln" Targets="Rebuild" Properties="Configuration=Release;" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```