# How to compile from command line using visual studio 2005

Tags: c++, batch-file, compilation, visual-studio-2005

I need to be able to compile a visual studio 2005 c++ project from the command line. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498106/how-do-i-compile-a-visual-studio-project-from-the-command-line) post in the SOF archives but it does not seem to help me solve my problem. I am not able to find neither msbuild or vcexpress. Can someone point me to where they must be or is there a different command for visual studio 2005?

What I need is to create a batch file that does the compiling.

Comment: Assuming you want to build a solution the command would be devenv /Build YourSolution.sln as noted in the second answer in your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click *Start*, point to *All Programs*, point to *Microsoft Visual Studio*, point to *Visual Studio Tools*, and then click *Visual Studio Command Prompt*.

To open the *Windows SDK Command Prompt* window (*Windows SDK* version 6.1 or later):
Click *Start*, point to *All Programs*, point to *Microsoft Windows SDK* , and then click *SDK Command Prompt* or *CMD Shell*.

And read [How to: Compile a Native C++ Program from the Command Line in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I need to be able to create the exe from the windows command prompt.

Comment: @istrandjev, Read the link above!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for cl.exe.
But, ehm, batch file? Don't you mean makefile?

Comment: Hmm maybe the word compiling was a bit confusing. I need to create a batch file that creates an .exe from the project and then do some stuff with it.

Comment: when I try to run cl.exe I get the error "The application failed to run because mspbd80.dll was not found." I could not find such dll anywhere in the installation folder of vs 2005.

Comment: Then you may have a configuration error. You could try re-running vcvarsall.bat. By the way, it's called mspdb80.dll.