# python script to open visual studio and build a project

Tags: python, wxpython

I have developed a GUI using wxpython for svn checkout.Now i need to build the checked out codes.I need to write a script to call visual studio and build the codes and display the msi created.All the above operation should happen in a single click on the button in the GUI.please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider running [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd393574.aspx) instead of going to all the trouble to automate Visual Studio.

Comment: Correct. There are some other methods you could try here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498106/how-do-i-compile-a-visual-studio-project-from-the-command-line