# Visual C++ 2010 Different configurations for multiple projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, configuration, configuration-management

I've got a solution with multiple projects. 
Now every project has its own configuration and nearly all projects do even have multiple configurations.
When building the projects I want that all configurations that do exist are built. Is there a way to do this automatically without picking every configurations by hand and start the building process over and over again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it by hand in MSVC GUI you can do the following:
 1. Right-click on the solution, in the popup menu go to the menu item "Batch build..."
 2. In the dialog that will appear, do "Select all" or just select the projects/configurations you need.
 3. Click button "Build" (or "Rebuild" if you prefer a clean build).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see that option in the IDE. But as far as I have seen I can't save such a batch, do I? Therefore I would always have to choose manually between Debug- and Release configurations which is not practicable in with a lot of Configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an [MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498106/how-do-i-compile-a-visual-studio-project-from-the-command-line) or NAnt script (or even a plain old batch file) to compile all the configurations so you don't have to do it all by hand.