# Building a VS2012 solution with Developer Command prompt

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498106/how-do-i-compile-a-visual-studio-project-from-the-command-line) thread which talks about building a solution from command prompt

It states that you need to do

```
msbuild project.sln  /Flags...
```

Now currently I have everything setup in VS2012 and all I do is build > Rebuild solution in debug mode.Everything is already setup in VS2012.I simply want to automate that process so In my batch file I do this

```
msbuild project.sln
```

However I do not specify any flags is there a difference between the two.
Isnt it suppose to pick up flags from the project.sln ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is "default to" logic in the csproj files.

example:

```
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
```

This says that if you don't pass in a Configuration value, (aka, it is equal to an empty string ''), then use "Debug" for the value.

Same for Platform and "AnyCPU".