# a build script that can compile and test the solution from the command line

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, msbuild

I am building a console application with visual studio 2013.  I'm given two requirements, and I need help with what exactly I need to do with #2.

1. Create a console application that does XYZ.
2. Solution must have a build script that can compile and test the solution from the command line.

My understanding was that the project file is just a build script.  But now I'm confused.  Do I need a separate build script to achieve this?  Or modify the existing project file?  Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compile a Visual Studio project from the command-line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498106/how-do-i-compile-a-visual-studio-project-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The csproj or vbproj files are the project files which MSBuild use to build the project when you hit build/rebuild from Visual Studio. You can call MSBuild from Visual Studio command prompt like:

```
MSBuild.exe MyProj.csproj /property:Configuration=Debug
```

Read [MSBuild Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms171452(v=vs.90).aspx) for more inforamtion.