# how to create .exe from CEF source code on windows (without using Visual studio)

Tags: windows, chromium-embedded, mingw-w64

i have downloaded CEF binaries from the link http://opensource.spotify.com/cefbuilds/index.html as successfully created a .sln file using VS 2017.
But now our requirement is to compile the cef binaries on windows through MinGW or through command line(Do not want to use Microsoft visual studio).
can someone helpme out with this thing?

Answer (score 0):

Only Visual Studio is officially supported to build CEF on Windows. You'll unlikely be successful to make a different compiler work in a reasonable time.

There is also ways to compile a VS project via the command line. Example: `msbuild project.sln /Flags...` For more details have a look at this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498106/how-do-i-compile-a-visual-studio-project-from-the-command-line)

If you ever want to compile libcef (Chromium) for Windows, the whole build is entirely command-line only despite using the Visual Studio compiler.

There is a free edition of Visual Studio called *Visual Studio Community* (used to be Visual Studio Express):
https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/

Also, if you are a small company, you might want to check out Microsoft's Action Pack for 400 EUR/year which includes 3 Visual Studio Prof. subscriptions.

Have a look at the CEF wiki:
https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart.md

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough points to comment on Eugen. Maybe someone can edit.

I think Eugen is right, and VS is a must. I suggest flowing also [this link](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/AutomatedBuildSetup.md) to learn how to build CEF programmatically and on different OS.