# How to create a MSIX package for a Win32 application without an installer

Tags: qt, installation, deployment, windows-installer, msix

I have a Qt application that I have deployed using [windeployqt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html). Now I have a folder on my disk, which contains a "MyApp.exe" and all the necessary Qt dll files to run this file (without installing anything else). I would now like to create a [MSIX package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/overview) for my application. I have downloaded the [MSIX Packaging Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/msix-packaging-tool/9n5lw3jbcxkf?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) from the Microsoft Store, running this tool I get the following screen stating that an installer isn't necessary:

[image: MSIX Packaging Tool]

After, clicking Next without filling the installer path and then filling the "Package Information" section. You get to this screen

[image]

Now, it is unclear to me how does one create a MSIX package without an installer and how can I instead create a package that deploys the content of my folder containing the executable generate by windeployqt. What instructions do I need to follow to correctly use the MSIX Packaging Tool to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The MSIX Packaging Tool is intended to be used by IT pros to create MSIX packages for apps where they don't have the source code. It is not designed for developers.

If you have access to your source code, which it sounds you do, then you can use Visual Studio or third-party tools like Advanced Installer to create the MSIX package.

This older SO question has more details: [How to build an MSIX from comandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64702212/how-to-build-an-msix-from-comandline/64715653#64715653)

Comment: My project builds using CMake. As far as I know, using the "Windows Application Packaging Project" template, it is not possible to add an application reference to a cmake project in Visual Studio 2019. Or is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't have any experience with cmake so can't help with that, sorry. If VS is not an option you might try the Professional edition of Advanced Installer. With Advanced Installer you can manually specify which files to be included in the MSIX package from Files and Folders page.  **Disclaimer**: _I work on the team building Advanced Installer_.