# MSI/Exe to MSIX package conversion process using pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, windows-installer, msix, windows-virtual-desktop

I have been looking everywhere to get some guidance on MSI/exe files to MSIX package using Azure DevOps pipelines. However, I am unable to find any information regarding that.
There are plenty of articles explaining the conversion process by using the tool but I am trying to automate the conversion process.
Can someone direct me to the right path and if its even possible to convert the files into MSIX package using pipelines.

Pipeline will help us alleviate issues regarding new binaries (in exe or msi format) being available and they can be package into an MSIX through pipeline.
Idea is to use these packages, create VHDX and attach it to an Azure virtual desktop (using MSIX app attach).
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked this： https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MSIX.msix-ci-automation-task

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the MSIX Packaging Tool. This tool is not recommended to be used if you have access to the source code.

The MSIX Packaging Tool is intended to be used by IT pros to create MSIX packages for apps where they don't have the source code. It is not designed for developers.

If you have access to your source code, which it sounds like you do, then you can use Visual Studio or third-party tools like Advanced Installer to create the MSIX package.

This older SO question has more details:    [How to build an MSIX from comandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64702212/how-to-build-an-msix-from-comandline/64715653#64715653)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Advanced Installer there is an option to convert MSI to MSIX.[image]