# How do I compile the output of CMake on Windows with MSVC from the command line?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, cmake

I have `cmake` and `make` set up on macOS and Linux and I am trying to port this build system to Windows.

On Windows I installed `cmake` and was able to run `cmake` with the `-G "Visual Studio 17 2022"` option, which works, but then I don't know what to do with the files it outputs. There is no `makefile`, so even when I installed `make` with `choco install make` I was not able to use `make`. There is a Visual Studio solution `.sln` file and some `.vcxproj` files, but  I can't find any information on what command I'm supposed to run next, since `make` does not work.

The documentation for [Running CMake](https://cmake.org/runningcmake/) says to run `cmake-gui.exe`, which isn't helpful to me. The command line instructions mostly describe the `cmake` command, and also mentions the `make` command, but it does not mention what command to use on Windows since `make` does not work.

Comment: If you want to compile from the command line, `Visual Studio ...` is probably the wrong generator. Prefer `-G Ninja` (on all platforms), and build with `cmake --build`, or directly with `ninja`. (But it should be possible to build a solution from command line using `devenv.exe`, and perhaps `cmake --build` can invoke it for you conveniently).

Comment: Thanks, `cmake --build` with Ninja works, and it's cross-platform so I can use this on Mac and Linux too.

Comment: If you do have to build a Visual Studio solution from the command line at some point: [How do I compile a Visual Studio project from the command-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498106/how-do-i-compile-a-visual-studio-project-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

The solution as mentioned by HolyBlackCat in the comments is to use `cmake --build` followed by a path, instead of `make`. This works cross-platform and should work with any generator, while `make` only works when CMake is told to output `"Unix Makefiles"`.

Also, the `Ninja` generator is preferred in this case, since it works cross-platform and (in my experience) results in faster builds than using the `Visual Studio`* generators.

These things are not mentioned in [the documentation](https://cmake.org/runningcmake/), so hopefully this helps someone.